Run-Time Error 3075: Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in Query Expression '[ParcelID]='
I have a Multiselect Listbox (listScanned) that shows records from a Table (TempDelivery). The Column shown in the ListBox is named ParcelID.
I want to be able to select items in this list and press a "Delete Button" to delete these records both from the listbox and the table.
Everytime I try to run the code I get the message:

Run-Time Error 3075: Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in Query Expression '[ParcelID]='.

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried the following code, trying different variations of ParcelID but I can't get it to work.
Private Sub deleteListItem_Click()

    Dim Var As Variant

    If Me.listScanned.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
    For Each Var In Me.listScanned.ItemsSelected
    CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * FROM TempDelivery WHERE [ParcelID]= " & Me.listScanned.Column(2, Var)

  Next

  Me.listScanned.Requery

  End If
End Sub


I moved my code to an answer but can't remove it from my edit of your question.

Just a typo: Delete * => Delete.

You can loop the listbox and delete in one go:
Private Sub DeleteListItem_Click()

    Dim Ids     As String
    Dim Index   As Long

    If Me!ListScanned.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
        For Index = 0 To Me!ListScanned.ListCount - 1
            If Me!ListScanned.Selected(Index) Then
                If Ids <> "" Then
                    Ids = Ids & ","
                End If
                Ids = Ids & Me!ListScanned.Column(2, Index)
                ' Clear selection
                Me!ListScanned.Selected(Index) = False
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print Ids
        CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * From TempDelivery Where PracelID In (" & Ids & ")"
        Me.Requery
        Me!ListScanned.Requery
    End If

End Sub


Just to let you know: the Staging Ground is for improving question quality, not for solutions.

@GertArnold: Thanks. I'm not familiar with the concept.
